# Rails: Generate Unique Random Number for populating a CSS class String How To?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, random, unique, erb

So let's say we have a rails view with this code:

```
<h1>Users who have the <%= @title.name %> Title</h1>
<ul>
  <% @title.users.each do |user| %>
    <li><%= user.username %> <div class="rw-ui-container rw-urid-X"></div></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

And what we want to do is to automatically *print* this line:

```
<div class="rw-ui-container rw-urid-X"></div>
```

Right aside each username the loop throws at us BUT we want **X** to be  a different **unique** random number each time...

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: my suggestion was to do something like his `<div class="rw-ui-container rw-urid-<%= user.id >"></div>` This will add the random ness dont you feel

Comment: True, but I wanted to make it more fun XD, besides if I need 1 user to have two different "X values" in different views userid is not enough. That's why I found wiseland's answer a little more elegant ;)

Comment: Y not use `UUID` to achieve the same

Comment: That would be an awesome approach too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this solution can help you:
 1. You can use `user_id` as first part of the random `X` to ensure that
    another user doesn't have it
 2. Second part is time in UTC format to set `X` different each time
 3. Third part is just a standart random func. You haven't use it if you want.

```
<h1>Users who have the <%= @title.name %> Title</h1>
<ul>
  <% @title.users.each do |user| %>
    <li><%= user.username %> <div class="rw-ui-container rw-urid-<%= "#{user_id}#{Time.now.utc.to_i}#{rand(100000)}".to_i %>"></div></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is cool, but everytime I reload the page, I get a different random number for everyone... is possible to set the random number to a fixed one after it is generated the first time?

Comment: Do you want to have different random numbers for one account even it's log in twice (from different computer for ex)? If yes, I will suggest you to generate random number once, write it in the session (cookie) and use it untill user log out or session expired.

Answer (score 0):

```
css_arr = ["rw-ui-container rw-urid-1","rw-ui-container rw-urid-2","rw-ui-container rw-urid-3"]

<div class="<%= css_arr.sample %>"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well You could easily add a new field to user table call 
 `uuid` or give it any name that you like and assign a unique id using the [gem](https://github.com/assaf/uuid/) called uuid

This help ensure that you have uniqueness in `X` section and also on refresh the value wont change as you mention in one of your comment

so here how your `X` code would look like

```
<% @title.users.each do |user| %>
    <li><%= user.username %> <div class="rw-ui-container rw-urid-<%=user.uuid %>"></div></li>
  <% end %>
```